# How to use same Partial for multiple resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, erb

I'm using tables to list recorded from database in index templates, And as usual the last three table cells are used for the links of Show, Edit and Destroy the Object.

**../users/index.html.erb**

```
<table>
  ...
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        ...
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Anyway, I was trying to replace those links text to some Bootstrap's glyph icons, And I succeeded but It got messy so I thought it better to put it in a partial with a variable to be shared with all index templates that use the same table layout.

**../shared/_editLinks.html.erb**

```
<td>
  <%= link_to dist do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
  <% end %>
</td>
<td>
  <%= link_to send("edit_#{dist}_path(#{dist})") do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
  <% end %>
</td>
<td>
  <%= link_to dist, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
  <% end %>
</td>
```

Then To use the following code line to render the partial in the index table. Passing the resource name as variable.

```
 <%= render 'editLinks', dist: user %>
```

Then the first and the last links seems to work fine but I got this error around the middle -Edit- link.

```
undefined method `edit_user_path(#<User:0x007f611ab015a8>)' for #<#<Class:0x007f611a7064d0>:0x007f611ab143b0>
```

Can you tell me what causes this error and how to get it work?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what "I'm tables to index records of any recourse" means.

Comment: Try `dist.id` once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines causing errors are because you're trying to treat an object like a string.

Because the `_path` helpers are typically `snake_case`, you can use the `underscore` method on the object's class name like so:

```
<%= link_to send("edit_#{dist.class.name.underscore}_path", dist) do %>
```

As pointed out by Deepak, you also can be providing the `dist` object as the second argument to `send`. Otherwise, you'll end up with a similar error because you'd again be treating the object as a value that can be coerced into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Pass param to route/method separated by comma

```
<%= link_to send("edit_#{dist.class.name.underscore}_path", dist) do %>
```

[`send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-send) method syntax

Comment: Thanks, But that returned the same error
`undefined method `edit_#<User:0x007f611a70e720>_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f611a7064d0>:0x007f6114a25ea0>`

Comment: ahh.. change `edit_#{dist}_path` to `edit_#{dist.class.name.underscore}_path`